# finding the network pc name and the ip adress from asp.net on local server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, networking, ip

I have to do a asp.net web page that when load will say something like

```
Hello NameOfThePCinTheNetwork
```

the page will be on the local server and only pcs from the local private network can access it, also i need the local ip address of the pc that access the page for some further work. I know that i can find the the public ip address with JavaScript but i dont need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get computer name:

```
string clientMachineName = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
```

Get LAN IP:

```
string GetIP4Address()
{
    string IP4Address = String.Empty;


    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
        if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
        {
            IP4Address = IPA.ToString();     
            break;
        }           
    }
    return IP4Address;
}
```

Comment: Kamyar i guess the method GetIP4Address() works when you are accessing by Network cable but when i try to use the clientMachineName it gives me " activate.adobe.com " and thats not the network pc name :)

Comment: Sorry i was wrong there were some JavaScript code that i didn't disable...The problem only acquires when trying to access the page with Opera browser with IE and Chrome its fine, thanks alot!